# button_onclick() generating in the .aspx page itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="R_VisitorManagementSyatem.Login" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
</script>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnlogin_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

I want the btnlogin_Click() function to come under .aspx.cs file. but why is this generating in the same file itself

Visual studio. asp.net c# project

Comment: Where is the <%@ Page directive?

Comment: Creating WebForms with code separation in Visual Studio https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbhbb82.aspx

Comment: did you add the event handler from properties of the button or double clicked from the designer view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the header file of your aspx file, There should be a property named CodeBehind. It shold look something like this:

```
CodeBehind="yourPage.aspx.cs"
```

It could aslo be called CodeFile.

```
CodeFile="yourPage.aspx.cs"
```

If it's not there the code is placed within the script tags of your aspx page. 
You'll need to add it to this line of code at the top of your page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="YourPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourPage" %>
```

EDIT Also
When you click 'Add New Item' and select 'Web Form' to add the new page to your project, there is a little checkbox in the bottom right corner that says 'Place code in separate file'. You may not have checked that which is why it puts the code in the aspx page

[image: Bottom right corner of this page]

I don't think you can go back and edit this if it was unchecked but it should be easy enough to create a new page, make sure this is checked and copy your code over.

Comment: When you click 'Add New Item' and select 'Web Form' to add the new page to your project, there is a little checkbox in the bottom right corner that says 'Place code in separate file'. You may not have checked that which is why it puts the code in the aspx page.

Comment: Thank you friend. Actually I was missing the codefile command in the page directive. I think it must have been accidentally deleted. by the way thankyou. now its working perfect